# Excel: calculage sum of matched cells multiplayed by percent in another cell

Tags: excel, percentage

I have an Excel table with my banks account like this

```
    A            B          C       E
1   Currency   Percent    Value     Banks Account
2   USD        5          100       8923781
3   Eur        7          200       Ea84382
4   USD        6          900       PayY8908
```

So I need to calculate how much USD I will earn in current month from all deposits (Value) if we know interest rate's (Percent) for each of bank's acoounts.
For first account the formula will be `=C2/100*B2/12` and for second `=C4/100*B4/12`

The problem that I don't understand how to automatically filter only USD accounts (SUMIF???). And I can't figure out how to do this using only one cell.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SUMIF, if you would use a helper Column:

```
   A        B       C       D               E
1 Currency  Percent Value   Banks Account   Monthly earned
2 USD       5       100     8923781         0,416666667
3 Eur       7       200     Ea84382         1,166666667
4 USD       6       900     PayY8908        4,5

Formula in E2:
=C2/100*B2/12
fill down.
```

Now you could have:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$10,"USD",$E$2:$E$10)
```

to sum the USD.

Or, without helper Column, you could use the "swiss army knife" SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$A$10="USD")*($C$2:$C$10/100*$B$2:$B$10/12))
```

Greetings

Axel